# How do I use AND logic to check if cell A1 and cell B1 have certain text, to return a value in cell C1

Tags: excel

Looks like this:

A | B | C
True | databasename.abc.flag | ??
IF(AND(A1"True",B1="flag"),"Success")

Answer (score 0):

Your formula looks close... does this get you what you're going for?

In C1:

```
=IF(AND(A1=TRUE,B1="flag"),"Success","Fail")
```

Comment: Nope, still error

Comment: dont know what error you're getting but could add IFERROR:

=IFERROR(IF(AND(A1=TRUE,B1="flag"),"Success","Fail"),"Fail")

Comment: I'm trying to see if cells A1 and B1 contain certain texts; if they both do, I need output for cell C1

Comment: I don't have excel on this computer to test but this might work: 

`=IF(AND(A1=TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("flag",B1))=TRUE),"Success","Fail")`

Comment: I still have a value populating in C1 when conditions aren't met, so I'm not sure.

Comment: C1 is where the formula is, correct?  If so, what value is returning when conditions are not met?

Comment: I should clarify my example. I have 7 columns, the formula is in G1. It checks for certain text in D1 and E1, and if that text exists in both cells, the value of B1 should show up in G1.

Comment: your formula worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could try in C1:

```
=IF(AND(A1=TRUE,B1="flag"),"Success",""
```

This should return an empty cell in C column if conditions are not met.